# Why the one ceil function gives out different answers?

Tags: java

I want to use ceil on the simple calculation by `Math.ceil`. 
However, `Math.ceil(3/2)` gives out 1.0, while `Math.ceil(1.5)` gives out 2.0, why is this?
Should I right this myself to make the ceiling operation on `3/2` to be 2.0?

Comment: isn´t it because you divide Integer in your first ceil? and 3/2 in Integer equals 1?

Comment: `3/2` is integer division, which results in 1.

Comment: @KevinEsche and nhahtdh: braindead just now ;) Should I delete the stupid question?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first case is equal to `Math.ceil(1)` since `3/2` is integer division.

Answer (score 1):

3/2 will return int so i won't carry floating values. But (1.5) is float type.
 
3/2=1 in java so Math.ceil(1)=1.0

So
Math.ceil(3/2) will return 1.0.
 and Math.ceil(1.5) return 2.0